# cURL file uploads not working anymore after upgrade from PHP 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: php, curl, php-5.6

I've got a cURL upload that fails after upgrading from PHP 5.5 to 5.6:

```
$aPost = array(
    'file' => "@".$localFile,
    'default_file' => 'html_version.html',
    'expiration' => (2*31*24*60*60)
)

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$sResponse = curl_exec ($ch);
```

The file seems to be empty on the target system.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Was the curl module included in the update? What OS is this? Have you eliminated other causes for the problem?

Comment: Yes, curl is working - files are empty (well the string gets sent out to the target system instead of the file) however. OS is CentOS, that hasn't changed between the updates.

Comment: (was adding my comment as you were adding your answer)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Actually I found the answer while starting the question. There is a new Variable included with curl in PHP 5.5: `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` this is set to `false` by default in PHP 5.5 and is switched to a default of `true` in PHP 5.6.

This will prevent the '@' upload modifier from working for security reasons - user input could contain malicious upload requests. You can use the `CURLFile` class to upload files while `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is set to `true` or (if you're sure your variables are safe you can switch the `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to `false` manually):

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

Here's a source for the information that got me searching in the right direction: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/87521

It's mentioned in the changed functions too: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php
But not in the backward incompatible changes, really tripped me off...

Comment: Note that setting CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD to false issues a deprecation message in PHP 5.5 or greater. Instead of `"@" . $localFile` just use `new \CURLFile($localFile)`. It's not that much harder. Of course, this class isn't available in PHP 5.4.

Comment: Looks like just setting `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to false does not work in PHP 5.6. The right and only way to get it working is the method suggested by @deepti-gehlot

Answer (score 32):

Just do following changes for PHP 5.5 or greater

Instead of `"@" . $localFile` just use `new CurlFile($localFile)`

And set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
```

Answer (score 10):

Include a runtime check to make your code compatible with lower versions too like below

```
$aPost = array(
    'default_file' => 'html_version.html',
    'expiration' => (2*31*24*60*60)
)
if ((version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5') >= 0)) {
    $aPost['file'] = new CURLFile($localFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
} else {
    $aPost['file'] = "@".$localFile;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$sResponse = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: The $post_array variable seems to be badly named, shouldn't it be $aPost?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to rename the variable..Thanks a lot. :)