# PHP 5.6< / cURL post file

Tags: php, curl

How could I post a file(path */var/www/* httpdocs/domain.com **/images/image.jpg**) from my website(server), to another website?

I tried this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$Url = "http://domain.com/insert.php";
$cookie_file = 'cookies.txt';
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('/images/image.jpg');
$fields = array(
            'type' => urlencode(1),
            'category' => urlencode(1),
            'title' => "Some title",
            'description' => "Some description",
            'file' => '@'.$file_name_with_full_path
);
$fieldsTrim = http_build_query($fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsTrim);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

but it does not work..

It sends everything except file...

Thanks

Comment: Is the path to file in the remote server absent  `$_POST['file']` ?
`$fieldsTrim = http_build_query($fields);` what is `$fields`? I don't see `$fields` in your code

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code.

Comment: So `$_POST['file']` is empty? Also syntax error there` 'file' => '@'.$file_name_with_full_path)` `)`

Comment: No $_POST['file'] is not empty when I trying to post image. Syntax error is just my over click here.

Comment: i simulate your code and take this http://c2n.me/3rBv1yp
all is fine;

Comment: Hmm, it's strange. Maybe the problem is in remote server.

Comment: Are you using `$_FILES` array to check for uploaded file? if not, check `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your code: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` 
Assuming that your `insert.php` is in the same server you are trying to upload the file to, this should work. Else, for PHP v5.6 you may try `curl_file_create()`. A nice tutorial is [**here**](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2014/06/14/how-upload-file-using-php-curl) which checks for `curl_file_create()` and if not, falls back to the older way of uploading file.

See Also: [cURL file uploads not working anymore after upgrade from PHP 5.5 to 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934128/curl-file-uploads-not-working-anymore-after-upgrade-from-php-5-5-to-5-6])