# Soundcloud PUT API returning 401

Tags: javascript, api, curl, soundcloud

I am trying to update soundcloud track details using HTTP API with CURL. I am getting 401 Unauthorized error as response eventhough I have passed my Client ID.

PUT  https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/11111111?client_id=12345666666

The response is

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "error_message": "401 - Unauthorized"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also wondering if I can pass access_token with the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass your token, simply append "&oauth_token=" + TOKEN_VALUE

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/11111111?client_id=12345666666&oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN

*Edited to add example code*

Here is an example of **PUT** using Curl & with PHP for soundcloud auth token. This code is from a working soundcloud project.

```
$data = array(
  'code' => $token,
  'client_id' => $this->getClientId(false), // your client ID
  'client_secret' => $this->getClientSecret(), // your client secret
  'redirect_uri' => $this->getCallback(), // callback URL
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
);
$url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";
try {
  $ch = curl_init();
  // set options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
  $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
  $body = substr($response, $header_size);      
  // read / process result
  curl_close($ch);
} catch(Exception  $e) {
  // error handling...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working for me, still showing error 401.

Answer (score 0):

This may work. Try turning off various CURL options. In my case I had PUT working under PHP5.5 but after migrating to new server with PHP7 the POST operation would fail until I set CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD to false for soundcloud POST operations (file uploads); however after making this change to all my curl inits, my PUT operations failed because they also had safeupload set to false, so I removed this setting from my PUT operations and the PUT operations started working.

In short, try turning off SAFE UPLOAD option for your PUT operations.

More info about this curl option on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25934129/1043316).