# Prestashop 1.4 fails when upgrading wamp 2.4 -> 3.0.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm trying to upgrade my work env to wamp 3.0.6,
I have an old prestashop 1.4.5.1 project that I have to maintain and the new WAMP refuses to cooperate

1. CURL fails to to send files (solved)

This is a php backward comparability bug where sending files with CURL doesn't work unless I add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` before `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

see [cURL file uploads not working anymore after upgrade from PHP 5.5 to 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934128/curl-file-uploads-not-working-anymore-after-upgrade-from-php-5-5-to-5-6/25934129#25934129) d

2. MySql returns empty queries

This is a MySql backward comparability bug - see [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/i-am-getting-an-error-in-mysql-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-qu)
I disabled this according to [Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)

hopefully I didn't break something there.

3. `rename(C:\wamp64\www\...\wrtC25B.tmp,C:\wamp64\www\..\01476c9c6b5f1091c73262cd3be476dcc853ec82.file.blockcart.tpl.php): Access is denied. (code: 5).`

Here is the code

```
        // remove original file
        if (file_exists($_filepath))
            @unlink($_filepath); 
        // rename tmp file
        rename($_tmp_file, $_filepath);
```

I tried to change the it to

```
        // remove original file
        if (file_exists($_filepath))
            @unlink($_filepath); 
        // rename tmp file
    copy ($_tmp_file,$_filepath);
    unlink($_tmp_file);
```

And I get `Permission denied`, I tried to change owner and give full control but still doesn't work.

However this problem normally disappear after a refresh (and then re-appear later) but I can ignore it since it doesn't break any thing else and happens only in the dev env.

4. Order creation failed

Order creation fails with message `Order creation failed`, this is caused because MySql doesn't accept empty (0000-00-00 00:00:00) date at insert any more, I solve it by adding

```
            $this->invoice_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $this->delivery_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

at line 200 file ObjectModel.php

This might be connected to issue number 2, since the related SO answer state that it could cause some other problems,

I was actually able to solve this but I keep this question for other to see and also if someone has better solutions.

Comment: For reasons like this I kicked my WAMP installation out the back door and switched to [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/why-vagrant).

Comment: Looking at Vagrant - it's is using VM which probably slows the local srv, no? wouldn't it be better to use a cloud9 IDE - which is also slow, but faster than a local VM AFAIK

Comment: VM eats some resources (you can set how much) but unless you have a really crappy PC or a very complex app that uses a lot of resources its ok and you can turn VM on/off with a quick command. You can have separate VMs for each project and only run the VM for the project you are working on. They can also be packaged and shared with other developers. This far outweighs the crap you have to deal with when you develop on local machine (specially on Windows) and you push code to webhost and everything breaks.